# Mars v2 Java compilation failures after upgrading to JDK 8u77

Tags: eclipse

I have OSX 10.10.3, JDK 8u77, Mars v2 (Eclipse 4.5.2.) and am getting

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project ...
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I've followed the advice for other questions and have reinstalled Eclipse, reinstalled Java, rebooted the box, thrown away my workspace, and re-created my .project and .classpath files from scratch.  It's still happening.

Can anyone advise?  Here's the stack trace from .metadata/.log :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getMethod(Scope.java:2804)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.ReferenceExpression.isPotentiallyCompatibleWith(ReferenceExpression.java:1012)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ConstraintExpressionFormula.reduce(ConstraintExpressionFormula.java:62)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BoundSet.reduceOneConstraint(BoundSet.java:844)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.InferenceContext18.reduce(InferenceContext18.java:861)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.InferenceContext18.solve(InferenceContext18.java:812)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ParameterizedGenericMethodBinding.computeCompatibleMethod18(ParameterizedGenericMethodBinding.java:234)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ParameterizedGenericMethodBinding.computeCompatibleMethod(ParameterizedGenericMethodBinding.java:82)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.computeCompatibleMethod(Scope.java:743)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.computeCompatibleMethod(Scope.java:700)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.findMethod0(Scope.java:1645)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.findMethod(Scope.java:1546)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MessageSend.resolveType(MessageSend.java:680)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MessageSend.resolveType(MessageSend.java:619)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MessageSend.resolveType(MessageSend.java:667)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.Expression.resolve(Expression.java:1020)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.resolveStatements(AbstractMethodDeclaration.java:641)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MethodDeclaration.resolveStatements(MethodDeclaration.java:309)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.resolve(AbstractMethodDeclaration.java:551)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.resolve(TypeDeclaration.java:1188)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.resolve(TypeDeclaration.java:1301)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.resolve(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:590)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.process(Compiler.java:861)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ProcessTaskManager.run(ProcessTaskManager.java:141)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

thanks,
Jon

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message

Comment: Edit the question and put the stack trace there.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I encountered the exact same stack trace.

Comment: When this happened to me, I did not upgrade the JDK. I was trying to run a junit test.

Comment: It resolved on its own.  I never determined the cause.  I've since switched to IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up upgrading to Oxygen to resolve this. I backed up my preferences before making the switch.